# Plot a 2D gaussian on numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, figure

I am a new in numpy and I try to practice the basic operations. Here is a code to plot a 2D gaussian distribution. I have an error in matplotlib. How can I fix that?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

X,Y=np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-1,1,10),np.linspace(-1,1,10));
mu,sigma=0,1; #suppose that mux=muy=mu=0 and sigmax=sigmay=sigma
G=np.exp(-((X-mu)**2+(Y-mu)**2)/2.0*sigma**2)
print G
fig=plt.figure();
ax=fig.add_subplot(111,projection='3d')
surf=ax.plot_surface(X,Y,G,c='red')
plt.show()
```

I have this error
**File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/__init__.py", line 4, in 
    from matplotlib.externals import six
ImportError: No module named externals**

Comment: Code works fine for me if I just copy and paste what you have written above. What version of python are you using?

Comment: @DavidG python 2.7 installed with macport

Comment: @MSeifert, I resolved the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because with my versions it works so I suspect you need to upgrade `mpl_toolkits` (and/or `matplotlib`).

It seems like `matplotlib` dropped support for older Python versions (and you have a more recent version) and therefore doesn't need an `externals` submodule anymore. But you didn't update `mpl_toolkits` which still thinks matplotlib has this submodule. And therefore you get this Error.